# Facing issues when deploying from Dev to UAT

Tags: email-validation

I have apex code where i used Email Statuses object to track the info whether sent mail is opened or not and how many times it opened.
All code coverage is met , but the problem is when i am trying to deploy it in to Uat from dev . When validating in uat org i am getting following errors.

> BatchToSegreggateLeads Apex Class  29  17  Invalid type: EmailStatus
>
> BatchToSegreggateLeads Apex Class  28  22  LastOpenDate,TimesOpened,WhoId From EmailStatuses) From Lead where id ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:96 Didn't understand relationship 'EmailStatuses' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
>
> BatchToSegreggateLeads Apex Class  29  36  Variable does not exist: EmailStatuses
>
> Test_BatchSegregateLeads  Apex Class  28  22  Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class Schedule_BatchToSegreggateLeads : Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class BatchToSegreggateLeads : LastOpenDate,TimesOpened,WhoId From EmailStatuses) From Lead where id ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:96 Didn't understand relationship 'EmailStatuses' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
>
> BatchToSegreggateLeads Apex Class  30  45  Variable does not exist: EmailStatuses
>
> BatchToSegreggateLeads Apex Class  35  23  Variable does not exist: em
> Schedule_BatchToSegreggateLeads Apex Class  28  22  Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class BatchToSegreggateLeads : LastOpenDate,TimesOpened,WhoId From EmailStatuses) From Lead where id ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:96 Didn't understand relationship 'EmailStatuses' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Please do help in this issue.

Comment: It sounds to me that the HTML Email Status Tracking feature is disabled in Setup. Can you please verify that this feature is enabled, found in [Activity Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_enable_email_tracking.htm&type=5)?

Comment: +sfdcfox Thanks bro !! it worked